# map function in javascript not working properly for React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a project in ReactJs.I have an array in javascript for which the values will come from the back-end.So, the length of the array will be dynamic.So, I want my UI to change if the array elements contain the string 'No Email Alerts'. So I am writing a map on my array components and trying to render it in the following way:

```
 {this.state.options.map((email, i) => {
          return (
            <Something />   
                {!(email[i].includes('No Email Alerts')) ? (
                  <Some_Other_UI />
                ) :

                  null}
```

But, the issue I am facing now is I am not able to exclude the part which contains 'No Email Alerts' and render the different UI. I mean my

```
{!(email[i].includes('No Email Alerts')) ? (
                      <Some_Other_UI />
                    ) :

                      null}
```

is not working. What am i doing wrong? Someone please guide me.

Comment: what error are you having ?

Comment: Why email[i] ??

Comment: You either need this.state.options[i] or just email .

Comment: Is email already an item instead of an array?

Comment: @MazinoSUkah It is not rendering accroding to the condition

Comment: Replace `email[i]` to `email`

Comment: i think you should try what @Kenny said

Comment: @sagi you mean to include `this.state.options[i]` inside my second conditon. Sorry I dint get what you meant.

Comment: Try `this.state.filter(email => filterCondition).map(email => <component .../>)`

Comment: You used email[i] , but email is not an array , it’s an instance of an element of the array. So to get this working, you need to replace what I said with email[i]

Comment: @Kenny I tried doing that, but it doesn't work.  it still doesnt go to the condition

Comment: @Rajesh it will have the same mistake as OP code.

Comment: @sagi  I tried the way you suggested, but its not working.Stil the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map parameters `email` and `i` is used for `this.state.options` and the `i` can be used for `this.state.options` array not just with `email` (you could use if email has similar indexes though). Also, you'll need to wrap them in an element or you may also use [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```
{
 this.state.options.map((email, i, arr) => {
   return (
     <div key={email+'-'+i}>{/* provide the key as you wish */}
        <Something />   
        {!(arr[i].includes('No Email Alerts')) ? (
           <Some_Other_UI />
         ) :
        null}
     </div>
   )
}
```

I would also suggest to use trim and check for lower case in includes like this:

```
!(arr[i].trim().toLowerCase().includes('no email alerts'))
```

Comment: Just one doubt, so what is the email parameter mainly used for? I mean what I was thinking is email loops over the whole array and maps for each element?

Comment: Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map